# Why team meetings are scheduled at lunch time, mostly?

Tags: software-industry, meetings, canada, lunch, scheduling

I am just trying to **understand other side** if any **good** reasons behind this scheduling.

**Background:**

I faced this with 2-3 managers who schedules weekly/monthly team meetings at **lunch time( 1-2 pm)** on when 90% of the people have lunch at designated area.

I feel irritated and sent them email asking reschedule **couple** of times and they did.

But they keep scheduling during lunch time again and I gave up.

They are working on the same floor.

I noticed they **mostly** prefer this time slot, but don't know why.

How to manage this situation?

Comment: Is your lunch time set - are you allowed to take an earlier lunch?  If the times are set, do people often bring their lunches to the meetings?

Comment: If you bring your lunch to work, simply take your lunch into the meeting with you.
if you go out for lunch,  go to lunch before the meeting or have it delivered to your office.

Comment: We are not allowed to eat during meetings and I myself don't prefer that even if it is allowed.

Comment: Why downvotes? It seems I have to just follow managers like sheep? Is that this community advising?

Comment: I haven't voted but you did ask two different questions: Why would someone schedule lunch meetings and how to handle that. I think the close vote for primarily opinion based is about the former. The latter question is a bit vague. I think you want to never have lunch meetings but it isn't clear whether you've actually asked for that or only sent one-off rescheduling requests for specific meetings.

Comment: *I noticed they mostly prefer this time slot, but don't know why.* Have you asked them?

Comment: @dwizum, I didn't ask them, but asking here hoping to get answers from multiple people(managers) than just my manager.

Comment: Vote to close.  a) Why does your team have lunchtime meetings?  No way for us to know, too localized.  b) 1-2 PM isn't generally considered lunchtime, what do you mean exactly?  Unclear. c) How do you handle this?   Depends what you want to happen. Agony aunt question.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, Yes, most people including managers have at 1pm. No one is bringing lunch to meetings. I think it shows I am not interested in that meeting and rude.no?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, Thanks for the comment, I got your point. _when a lunch meeting is required, lunch is either provided_  - I never heard this in any company in my experience in Canada & India, People will love lunch meetings then...lol

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If they're like some companies I've worked for, that's when they can find an available time for everyone.   They probably don't prefer the time...it's just when they can get a free hour for everyone.   Don't like it?   Speak up directly and tell them this isn't a good time, or block your time on the calendar

Comment: +1 for speaking to them or using the calendar. You're right about the scheduling though; _their_ availability is limited, that of the worker minions is not. Much as it irritates me, I can see the necessity.

Comment: Yes. Why do they do this?  **Ask them.** They'll answer.

Comment: I accepted for _block your time on the calendar_

Answer (score 3):

If this is occurring in the US, a **lot** of people go to lunch right at noon. Because it's usual to take an hour lunch, scheduling a meeting at 1 pm probably makes sense to someone who eats at noon. It also has the benefit of keeping the rest of the group on the roughly the same schedule.

I prefer to eat later, myself, so the day is broken up more evenly and you get to miss the lunch rush.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what type of environment you're in (consulting, startup, corporate, etc), but I often see this in the consulting world, where time is tracked as billable.

Team meetings aren't billable to clients, which means that people try to limit them and/or schedule them during times when people aren't doing billable work. This results in team meetings scheduling during lunches (eat & meet simultaneously) or late/early in the day when team members are less likely to have client meetings scheduled.

Even outside of consulting work, meetings can often be viewed as slight annoyances or time fillers (even though they are definitely important). Scheduling over lunch is a way to recognize the fact that meetings need to happen, but while trying to avoid using up valuable work time.

Comment: This is at client bank where developers are both from client bank and consulting company(like me).